# Proper word to describe the time spent on delivering a mail by post

Tags: word-usage

Grateful if you would share with me a proper word/term to describe the period of time used for processing and delivering a mail.

Comment: There's no such word.

Comment: You might call the period between posting and receiving the ***transit time***. In a suitable context where you're going to need to reference this quantity a lot, you could reasonably shorten it to just ***transit***.

Comment: @Oldcat - I wonder if the Postal Service has a name for it.

Comment: They might, but it is still just jargon.

Comment: @medica: The length of time between you posting a letter and the mailman collecting it from a box is part of the ***transit***, but mail delivery systems couldn't possibly know that.

Comment: I would call that the *handling time*, because it encompasses every second between the sender depositing their mail in a letterbox or at a post office, and the mail/postal carrier delivering it to its destination. But for authoritative answers you should really approach the mail delivery agencies/postal services operating in the country (or countries) in question. Especially today, when all kinds of efficiency-related metrics are being used in commerce and industry (including service industries), they will almost certainly have their own technical terms for this time interval.

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe that both transit time and handling time are correct depending on the context.

Comment: Any more, "two weeks" is about right.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you don't say "delivering a mail". It's "a piece of mail" or "a letter" or "a package".  You might have gotten confused because people often refer to "an e-mail" or "[x] e-mails" when they mean "an e-mail message" or "[x] e-mail messages" respectively.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question about the time period that it takes?

Comment: Nothing at all. It's an aside ("By the way,") addressing the OP's mistaken usage "a mail".  And thank you for asking.

Comment: It should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Noted with thanks. "A mail" was used for letter, package, email and etc. in general. Grateful if you could let me know a more proper expression.

Comment: say "a letter" if you mean a letter; "a box" if you mean a box. "A parcel" or "a package" could include any piece of mail other than a letter. And "a piece of mail" includes both letters and packages. As for e-mail, I prefer to call individual pieces of e-mail "messages", but most of the English-speaking world seems to think that "e-mail" is a count noun, even though "mail" isn't. I have never heard a good reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

When a seller sends an item to me, and it has left the country but not yet arrived, it's listed as "in transit".

Answer (score 0):

**Delivery time**

[Googling](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mail+transit+time) for *mail transit time* shows that this is what postal services generally call it.